# Can't set Debian 8 machine to correct time?

Tags: debian, timezone

I need to do so my Debian server and my personal computer is on the same timezone (and time of course), which is Europe/Copenhagen, +1 GMT.

If I change my Debian 8 machine to Europe/Copenhagen with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` I get this result:

```
Current default time zone: 'Europe/Copenhagen'
Local time is now:      Tue Nov 22 09:09:38 CET 2016.
Universal Time is now:  Tue Nov 22 08:09:38 UTC 2016.
```

But the time is actually 14:09:38 in Denmark. I'm not sure if this is an error on the machine or I'm misunderstanding all this. I've tried searching for some answers but I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: `apt-get install chrony`

Comment: If my arithmetic is correct, the current time on your kernel clock is what would result from confusing Central Time with Central _European_ Time, mistakenly setting your hardware clock to your local time as if it were Central Time, and then not telling Debian that your hardware clock is running in local time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the `ntp` package then edit your `/etc/ntp.conf` as follows:

```
server 0.dk.pool.ntp.org
server 1.dk.pool.ntp.org
server 2.dk.pool.ntp.org
server 3.dk.pool.ntp.org
```

Allow the incoming `ntp` packets through the firewall e,g (`ufw`):

```
ufw allow ntp
```

Restart the service:

```
/etc/init.d/ntp restart
```

Run `dpkg-reconfigure ntp` then `ntpq -p`

Also you can use `timedatectl` command

```
timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Copenhagen
```

Edit the `timesyncd.conf` file:

```
nano /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf
```

add the following:

```
FallbackNTP=server 0.dk.pool.ntp.org server 1.dk.pool.ntp.org server 2.dk.pool.ntp.org server 3.dk.pool.ntp.org
```

Synchronize:

```
timedatectl set-ntp true
```

verify using `timedatectl`:

output example:

```
Local time: Tue 2016-11-22 17:41:05 CET
Universal time: Tue 2016-11-22 16:41:05 UTC
    RTC time: Tue 2016-11-22 16:41:05
    Time zone: Europe/Copenhagen (CET, +0100)
    NTP enabled: yes
 NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
 DST active: no
 Last DST change: DST ended at
              Sun 2016-10-30 02:59:59 CEST
              Sun 2016-10-30 02:00:00 CET
 Next DST change: DST begins (the clock jumps one hour forward) at
              Sun 2017-03-26 01:59:59 CET
              Sun 2017-03-26 03:00:00 CEST
```

Answer (score 0):

You **should** get your time from `ntp` in Debian. Check if `ntp` is installed, if not follow the guide in  **[this link](https://wiki.debian.org/DateTime)** to get it up and running.

> Set the time automatically
>
> The protocol used to set the time is the Network Time Protocol or NTP.
>   To set the time automatically you need access to an NTP server. Your
>   local network may provide such a server but most people need to access
>   an NTP server via the internet.

Answer (score 0):

For Europe /Copenhagen :Universal Time UTC rather than CET and CEST. It's yes

Comment: Welcome on U&L! May you can elaborate a bit on this? It looks like you have some good understanding of what is going on, but it would probably be hard for the OP - and others that may find your answer helpful - to practically turn your answer into a solution to their problem.